# LTI system impulse response

Tags: linear-systems, impulse-response

I am learning signal processing and need some help with this question

$h[n]=-x[n]+2x[n-1]-3x[n-3]$

Given the following input signal $x[n]$ calculate y[n] the output of the system $x[0]=2, x[1]=0, x[2]=1, x[3]=-1$

What is my first step?

Comment: First step is to copy the question on your homework correctly into what you have written above.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a Homework kind of problem, hence only hint will be given)

Firt Step would be to figure out $h[n]$ as a finite length sequence.

Like your input $x[n] = \{ \hat{2}, 0, 1, -1 \}$.

And, given $h[n] = -x[n]+2x[n-1]-3x[n-3]$, put $x[n]=\delta[n]$ and get $h[n]$ as a finite length sequence.

And, then convolve $h[n]$ with $x[n]$ to get the output $y[n]$.